# Android studio 3.0 got Error SHA-256 digest error for org/jacoco/agent/rt/RT.class

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-performance

After I update Android studio to 3.0 and migrated my project by following this [instruction](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=772cbe6388-android-weekly-281&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-772cbe6388-337969913)

I got the error like this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDevDebug'.
> SHA-256 digest error for org/jacoco/agent/rt/RT.class
```

I tracked and found that the root cause came from this code in build.gradle file.

```
debug {
    ...
    // Run code coverage reports by default on debug builds.
    testCoverageEnabled = true
}
```

Because when I commented this line of code the project built fine. I haven't got this problem when I used Android Studio 2.3.

I had searched some related topics and found that somebody said disable instant run will solve but unfortunately in not work for my case.

Dose anyone has any suggestion to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2**:

Firebase Support still says the fix is not rolled out, but I tried it out today with the latest versions of `firebase-perf` and `jacoco` and it works.

**UPDATE 1**:

`firebase-perf` doesn't work with `jacoco` when [Java 1.8 support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) is enabled. Firebase support team was able to replicate this and is investigating.

**Original post**:

This looks to be triggered when `firebase-perf` plugin is enabled. I filed a bug with Firebase team and will update if I get an answer.

As a temporary workaround, just commenting out `apply plugin ... firebase-perf` should help. It will disable [Automatic Traces](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/automatic) but `@AddTrace` and `newTrace` should still work.

In my case `testCoverageEnabled` is set conditionally based on a project property and I didn't need firebase-perf plugin for when evaluating the coverage, so I just disabled the plugin:

```
if (!project.hasProperty('coverageRun')) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}
// < ... >
if (project.hasProperty('coverageRun')) {
    testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you specify what versions do you use? I've tried with latest: firebase(12.0.1) and jacoco(0.8) and have no success.

Comment: @temnoi it worked for me with firebase(11.4.2) and jacoco(0.7.9); FWIW I have `android.enableD8=true` in my `gradle.properties`.