# Firebase Performance Monitoring library not compatible with libraries distributed as signed jars

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, androidx, firebase-performance

After updating my project to AndroidX and targetSdkVersion from 27 to 28, I'm getting the following gradle error when I try to build:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginFor[Flavour]'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for META-INF/maven/at.favre.lib/bcrypt/pom.xml
    at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:218)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:241)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:212)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArrayInternal(ByteStreams.java:181)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:221)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.Instrument.instrumentClassesInJar(Instrument.java:105)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebaseTransform.transformJarInputs(FirebaseTransform.java:230)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebaseTransform.transform(FirebaseTransform.java:192)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor899.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
```

The error points to the [Bcrypt](https://github.com/patrickfav/bcrypt) library used in the project. But I've verified the jar signature with `jarsigner` and it's valid.

I'm using:

- Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13
- Gradle 4.10.2
- Android Plugin for Gradle 3.2.0
- Firebase Performance Monitoring Gradle Plugin 1.1.5
- Firebase Performance Monitoring 16.1.2

If I remove the Firebase Performance Monitoring dependency from the project everything works fine.

There is [a similar issue posted in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032877/android-studio-3-0-got-error-sha-256-digest-error-for-org-jacoco-agent-rt-rt-cla), but it was caused by jacoco. I don't use jacoco at all.

Any ideas? Thank you.

---

**Update 12/10/18:**

Sample app that reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/davidmigloz/firebase-performance-bug

**Update 26/10/18:**

I've been able to reproduce the bug using Firebase Performance Monitoring library together with any other library that is distributed as a **signed jar**.

**Update 26/10/18:**

If I enable Instant Run I get the same error (although for a different file) but in the Instant Run gradle task:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for at/favre/lib/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptFormatter.class
```

Comment: did you tried to change the firebase version ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with Firebase Performance Monitoring 16.1.0 (the one I'm currently using in production) but I get the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Support Team has confirmed me that is a bug in their end. But they have suggested this temporal workaround:

> We looked into this and found a bug. However, were able to figure out a
>   workaround for this for you:
>
> Step 1) In your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, update the
>   distributionUrl:
>
> `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip`
>
> Step 2) In your top level `build.gradle` file update the Android
>   Gradle Plugin:
>
> `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha05'`
>
> Step 3) In your `gradle.properties` file add below line:
>
> `# Blacklist libraries from being Jetified`
>   `android.jetifier.blacklist=bcrypt,bytes`
>
> Step 4) Clean Build the Project
>
> Running `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug` should succeed now.
>
> While we are working on the fix please use the above workaround to get
>   you up and running. My apologies for the wait here once again.

Comment: Do you have any sources on this?

Comment: my email to Firebase support?

Comment: The last updated I got (04/02/19): > Thanks for your continued patience so far. I wanted to reach out and let you know that we have identified the problem and are working on a fix for this right now. Currently, there are no further updates or ETAs that I can provide at this moment. Rest assured, we are doing everything on our end to get this rolled out soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is fixed on the new Firebase Gradle Plugin version (1.2.0).
You still need to use AS 3.4 with the 3.4 Android Gradle Plugin.